# Return a collection of objects from JAX_WS web service

Tags: java, jax-ws

in my web service I want to return a collection of objects depends on the client request for example (collection of strings , custom class ..) ,
My code :

```
@XmlRootElement(name="ResultObject")
public class ResultObject
{
private Object _Contents;  // this object should contain the collection
private int _ErrorCode;

.....
}
```

but when trying to return an ArrayList or Array of strings the following exception appear:

> Dec 30, 2012 5:49:21 PM
>   com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate doGet SEVERE:
>   caught throwable javax.xml.ws.WebServiceException:
>   javax.xml.bind.MarshalException
>    - with linked exception: [javax.xml.bind.JAXBException: class java.util.ArrayList nor any of its super class is known to this
>   context.]
>         at com.sun.xml.ws.message.jaxb.JAXBMessage.writePayloadTo(JAXBMessage.java:322)
>         at com.sun.xml.ws.message.AbstractMessageImpl.writeTo(AbstractMessageImpl.java:142)
>         at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.StreamSOAPCodec.encode(StreamSOAPCodec.java:108)
>         at com.sun.xml.ws.encoding.SOAPBindingCodec.encode(SOAPBindingCodec.java:265)
>         at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.encodePacket(HttpAdapter.java:320)
>         at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.access$100(HttpAdapter.java:93)
>         at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter$HttpToolkit.handle(HttpAdapter.java:454)
>         at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.handle(HttpAdapter.java:244)
>         at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.ServletAdapter.handle(ServletAdapter.java:135)
>         at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doGet(WSServletDelegate.java:129)
>         at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServletDelegate.doPost(WSServletDelegate.java:160)
>         at com.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.servlet.WSServlet.doPost(WSServlet.java:75)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
>         at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)

after searching for the solution some of posts advice to use annotations but the _Contents object is dynamic collection and I can't fix it's content .

please advice , Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The _Contents member needs a [@XmlAnyElement](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/XmlAnyElement.html) annotation, but I am not so fimilar with that. Maybe this article will help you: [Using @XmlAnyElement to Build a Generic Message](http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/using-xmlanyelement-to-build-generic.html)